# Best way to make duplicate copies of existing ASPX page in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms

What is the best way to create a copy of an existing ASPX page in a web project in Visual Studio?

If I right click on the ASPX file in the Solution Explorer and select copy, then paste, it looks like what I was expecting. I get a new copy of the ASPX file and the code behind files. I can then rename the ASPX file and the code behind files get renamed as well.

Looking good, until I open the ASPX file. Then I see that it has the same "Inherits" tag that the original file had, and it points to the orginal class name.

Is there something that I am missing? I realize I can mannually edit this, and the code behind files (since they are declaring the same class name, which causes build errors). Is there a better way to do this, or should I just man up and start doing some manual work? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I almost always create a brand new page, then just copy the "guts" (leaving page directive info, namespaces, etc) followed shortly by some find and replace if needed.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping for something more elegant but hey, if it works, it works!

Comment: This is what I always did until I recently found the method I placed in my answer below. It feels like less work than the copy\paste method which I'm always afraid I will paste something into the wrong file at 3am. Just changing a few properties feels like a better approach to me.

Answer (score 8):

The following works in VS 2013

1. Copy and paste the desired aspx page using VS right click copy\paste.
2. Rename aspx page using right click 'rename'.
3. Change Inherits tag at top of aspx page to the new name. (be aware - not all characters allowed).
4. View Code.
5. Change name of Class to match the Inherits tag in step 3.

Comment: This exact steps in this exact order work also on VS 2017 with this addendum: then change all the textBox ID's and OnTextChanged labels in the aspx code (not on the cs code), and let the designer fix your cs code, otherwise the aspx.designer.cs may get messed up. You can modify some of the aspx in Design mode (tab), but often you need to use Source mode (tab).

Answer (score 2):

I think Resharper has a 'Duplicate' refactoring that works on ASPX's as well. The default shortcut should be Ctrl-D

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how this command is invoked? By right-clicking on the page, and looking into the Refactor submenu, I can not find any 'Duplicate' command. I use VS2010 and Resharper v7.0.1 for C#.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - so no need for an answer, but I am leaving this here as I think others may find it useful.

What I did is to open one of the aspx page aspx.designer.vb files (they are all identical for my identical code-behind files) and copy the auto-generated WithEvents declarations for the controls.

I then turned the aspx.vb and aspx.designer.vb files into blank files (when I deleted them, the compiler complained that it couldn't find them - not sure yet how to fix that).  Magic!  All my aspx files now point to my new class (and file) and I no longer have the duplicated code.

By the way, this is not just a case of using multi-tier design.  I already had all the substantive code in one place, but I still had to duplicate the calls from Page_Load and various control click functions into that code.  Now I have nothing duplicated...

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Brian's answer.

In VS2013.

- Highlight the .aspx you want to copy
- Click CTRL-C, then CTRL-V

You'll see a new aspx created with the same with " - Copy.aspx" at the end

- Highlight the new .aspx
- Right-mouse click and select "Rename..."

Type what you want the new .aspx called.  Inherits, etc. are updated automatically.

Comment: I just tried this and renaming the .aspx did NOT automatically update the Class name or inherits line. Also, be sure you do NOT right-click the copied class name and chose Refactor -> Rename...! It will overwrite the source files class name and bork your project.

Answer (score 0):

i allready try it and it faild.... so i copy every paragraph on the aspx page alone and paste it in the right place

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32062821)